# Amok Time, as in “Run Amok”?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, title-explanation

Regarding  the *Star Trek* episode “Amok Time”, I always assumed “Amok” was a fictional sci-fi word, but then I realized it’s spelled the same as “to run amok”. Is there an intentional connection  there, as in “it’s time to run amok”?

Comment: Your answer seems to be provoking people to explain what the word "[amok](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amok)" means.

Comment: @Valorum: That is what I think is being asked here. As the OP is not making the connection between the word "amok" and the episode's events (which include Spock "running amok"), I have to assume the OP is unaware of the word's meaning.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - except that the question explicitly states that they *do* know what the meaning of the word is.

Comment: @Valorum: If that were the case, the connection between the word and the episode seems obvious. Which is why so far 3 out of 4 answers explain that connection by referring to the definition of the word.

Comment: @Valorum: To be clear: I understand this question as: "Is the term 'amok', used in the episode title 'Amok Time', a made-up sci-fi word that just happens to coincide with the actual loanword 'amok', found in 'to run amok', or is the word in the episode title actually an occurrence of said loanword?" How can this question be answered? By checking the meaning of the loanword "amok", as presented by commonly accepted sources (i.e. dictionaries). If that meaning matches with what is shown in the episode, we can conclude that the term in the title is indeed meant to be that very loanword, ...

Comment: ... rather than a made-up word that happens to be spelt the same way as the loanword. And that is what, in my opinion, and apparently at least in that of two more answerers, fully satisfactorily answers the question. If that is not the intended core of the question, I'd kindly ask the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Sure, but merely defining the word doesn't do anything to a) prove that it's what the writers intended and b) I think we can do a hell of a lot better than just providing the dictionary definition of the word "Amok".

Comment: @Valorum: It's not about "defining the word". It's about showing, with sources, that the word fits the episode content and therefore, it's really this word that was used in the title rather than something else that happens to be spelt the same. I'm not sure what further evidence you expect to see - short of an explicit statement by a writer along the lines of "yes, when I wrote 'amok', I meant the English word, rather than making up my own scifi term", that's as close as we're going to get. What can possibly be "better" than the dictionary definition, if that definition answers the question?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Yes. That would make an excellent answer. By comparison, simply copying and pasting from wikidictionary makes for a terrible answer.

Comment: @Valorum: If "That would make an excellent answer." refers to "showing, with sources, that the word fits the episode content and therefore, it's really this word that was used in the title rather than something else that happens to be spelt the same", then that is exactly what [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/240514/21137) does. Yet, [you seem to somehow expect further evidence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240512#comment660605_240514). Please clarify what you think is actually missing in the answers you commented on.

Comment: I'm chatting to get a hat. It's Dec. 21st!

Answer (score 22):

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amok), one of the definitions of "amok" as an adverb is:

> 2. in a murderously frenzied state

and as an adjective, it is described as

> possessed with or motivated by a murderous or violently uncontrollable frenzy

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/amok) categorizes the word as a noun described as

> 1. a state of murderous frenzy, originally observed among Malays

And [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/amok) provides the noun definition

> (among members of certain Southeast Asian cultures) a psychic disturbance characterized by depression followed by a manic urge to murder.

This describes Spock's out-of-control state which, at the climax of the episode, turns into some kind of a violent bloodlust.

Therefore: **Yes, I'd say there is an "intentional connection" - the episode title "Amok Time" simply uses the English term "amok" to literally describe Spock's behaviour in the episode.**

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is a reference to Pon Farr being a *time* when Vulcans become *amok*, i.e.

> in a violently raging, wild, or uncontrolled manner<sup>[[1]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amok)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The title appears to be a reference to an earlier script written by Herschel Daugherty for the episode *Operation - - Annihilate!*

In the original script (which forms the basis of James Blish's [novelisation of the episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Amok_Time_(episode))) Spock is accused of "running amok" by Kirk. Although the line was ultimately removed from the shooting script, it appears to have stuck in Roddenberry's mind and was used as the title of the subsequent episode.

> “Sir, I would prefer to bear it just a little while longer. The final
> test of the theory is what happens to me-or does not happen-when that
> nucleus is destroyed. If the pain continues, we will know that we were
> wrong.”
>
> **“Without prejudice to your own wishes or your will power, Mr. Spock,
> are you certain that there’s no danger of your running amok again?”**
>
> “The danger exists,” Spock said levelly. “However, I am fighting it.
> And I do not see how we can forfeit this test.”

Comment: also the "Time" bit being used in the 1st season already w/ "The Naked Time" in which the crews basest emotions were nakedly revealed due to an infection

Comment: @NKCampbell - I thought about adding that. "***Something** Time*" seems more than a little coincidental

Comment: @NKCampbell: Maybe I'm misinterpreting your comment, but wouldn't the most straightforward interpretation of why the word "time" was used be that the title refers to ... well, a particular *time*? There sure are more episodes where some or all of the crew lose emotional control one way or another, and the others had no "time" in the title ("This Side of Paradise" being just one example).

Comment: Wait, so your answer seems to be about a different episode. Do these 2 episode have a connection? What am I missing?

Comment: they aren't connected in anymore than both of them have Spock losing emotional control @RedCaio - I can't find any information that the title for 'Amok' was chosen specifically because of the season 1 episode - it's is interesting though

Comment: @RedCaio - The connection is that there was a line in the previous episode about Spock 'running amok' when he lost emotional control. Roddenberry was directly involved in writing (or at least editing) both episodes. They were also written back-to-back with both intended for inclusion in the latter part of season 1

Comment: This answer reads like a random guess and is, IMHO, rather far-fetched. Whoever came up with the episode name "Amok Time" could have learned about the term "amok" from all kinds of sources - basically, any media containing the term published by the year the episode was made in - and this answer contains no evidence it was this script among all possible options that gave the writer the decisive idea.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - So you don't think the fact that the person who co-wrote both episodes has any relevance with the fact that the wording appeared in one script, then turned up in the very next script?

Comment: @Valorum: No, why in the world should that have any relevance? It seems likely quite some of the other words from the first script (such as "sir", "I", "would", "prefer", ...) turned up in the very next script, as well. The assumption they turned up because the writer remembered them from the previous episode, *not because they simply are English words that fit in the given context*, seems rather outlandish to me.

Comment: one thing to remember is that scripts in TOS era came from ideas internal to the team that were then farmed out to sci-fi writers - so, as Valorum states @O.R.Mapper - Roddenberry came up w/ the idea (and it was worked on as well by Coon and Fontana) title and then farmed the script out to Ted Sturgeon for actual writing. Amok Time was originally meant to be written and produced during S1 but Sturgeon was slow. Thus - it wasn't written or ideated after "Operation: Annihilate" - in fact, Amok Time was started prior to "O:A"! so the 'amok' in that script may come from Amok Time!....

Comment: ...[see 'These Are the Voyages, Vol 2] - so yes, to Valorum's point - it certainly seems likely it was intentional from Roddenberry as they were worked on around the same time

Comment: @NKCampbell: I get that the scripts were in the hands of the same people at roughly the same time. But none of that is even indirect evidence that the word "amok" in either script was influenced by the other script. Both scripts happened to contain instances of someone "running amok" - under quite different circumstances -, and a suitable English word was used to describe that behaviour. It *might* be the case that a writer read the word in one of the scripts, and then, while writing the second script, the word popped up in their mind *precisely due to remembering it from the first one*. ...

Comment: ... But without any actual evidence for this particular chain of events - which this answer still entirely lacks - this is nothing but guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/240514/89101), there is such word in Malay.

From my knowledge, this word became well-known from a [story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amok_(novella)) by Stefan Zweig. The story basically describes an amok run.